# In OLS regression in R, how can I tell my model an observation is in my dataset more than once?

Tags: r, regression, time-series, multiple-regression, least-squares

First of all an example dataset, both a picture and the R code to generate it. Here, `X1` represents the ID of the individual / observation, `X2` some factor1 and `X3` some factor2.

[image]

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 4))
df[1:10,1] <- c(rep(1,2),2:9)
df[1:10,2] <- c("A","B", rep("A",8))
df[,2] <- as.factor(df[,2])
df[,3] <- c("XYZ", "XYZ", rep("ABC",8))
df[,3] <- as.factor(df[,3])
df[,4] <- c(5,5,runif(8))
```

If I would construct a linear model from this, my linear model in R (using `lm()`) will think I have 10 observations, while in fact I have 9. As you can see, the first two lines belong to observation/individual 1, but because this individual has two values for `factor X2`, it is shown twice in my dataset.

In my reallife dataset I have a lot of these cases. My dataset has 4.500 (4.5K) observations, and has a length of 60K+ because an individual can have multiple values for the same factor (for every factor in my dataset).

How can I let my linear model in R know that the first two lines are from the same observation? Is it through weights, or should I not use OLS to begin with?

**EDIT**
In my real situation I have historical sales data (time series) for many products. To make predictions about these sales, I employed some time-series methods (e.g. exponential smoothing, ARIMA). Furthermore, I need to make predictions about sales for other products for which I *do not have historical sales data*. These are new products and I'd like to make an estimation about their sales, based on the products that *do have sales data*. In addition to having sales data, for each product I have product information at a more detailed level: all factors (e.g., color of the product, design, ...). The problem I have is that the weekly sales are on a less detailed product level (e.g., sales of a t-shirt in multiple colors, designs, ...).

My idea was to make a linear model using OLS, for which I use the average weekly sales as response (`X4` here) in function of product information (`X2` and `X3`). Then I would like to use this model and make predictions for new products for which I have such production information like `X2` and `X3`. The problem (if it is a problem) is that I now have observations/products in my dataset more than once, due to the product information being on a more detailed level (e.g., the t-shirt in colors blue and red).

Comment: 1) Are you trying to include multiple observations from the same person in the same model (e.g. are trying to model X2)? Or 2) are you trying to remove points that should not be in the model?

Comment: Sorry, I did not include my response variable in the example. I editted it. X4 is the variable I would like to model in function of X2 and X3. Note that the response is always the same for an observation that is in the dataset multiple times (i.e.: line 1 and 2 in my example).

Comment: Unless you are doing something in the field of quantum physics, how does a single observation have two different values for a variable at the same time?  Surely you must be missing another variable that tracks time or some other dimensions that tracks observation order or something.  I think you'll need to explain your data in a real-world context for us to fully understand based on the number of modifications and edits you've made.  Can you tell us what your data represents in a real-world context?

Comment: Updated the question and deleted some of the comments.

Comment: Editted some more. I hope I made things clearer now, thank you so far for your input!

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, it sounds like you don't have any sales information on the new product, so you are simply using an old similar product as a proxy?  I'm not sure if you will get any great predictions here (and since you don't have any sales data, you can't even tell).  For example, maybe you have two 4th of July T-shirts:  one in red, white, and blue (RWB) colors and the other in black.  I don't think it's would be valid to use the RWB shirt as a proxy for the sales of the black shirt.

Comment: Also, it sounds like you are adding in an observation (ID 1) above for data you don't even have sales data on, but you've simply inserted the response a similar product for the one you don't.  Why do this at all?  Why not simply leave out the new product and then try to tease out aspects of the exiting product that contribute to sales?  For example, what effect on T-shirts does a certain color have?  Long sleeves, etc?  You may be able to determine the expected additional sales from each attribute and then use these to predict sales for the new item.  The question then is, are they additive?

Comment: Your first comment: correct. Second comment: I want to do exactly what you're saying, but apparently I am missing something. So, I have product information on both products (product with sales data, and product without sales data). I want to make a linear regression model based on the product with sales data, where my response variable is the average weekly sales of this product. Now, I have more than just two products - I have about 4500+ products with sales data, 700 products without. I thought each of the 4500 products would be an observation with its number of sales.

Comment: The thing is, my explanatory variables are all factors. And each product can have multiple values of the same factor (e.g., red, white, blue color). That's why my data seems to 'blow up' and that's why I am not sure if my approach is correct (my linear model seems to think I have much more observations than 4500: about 50K). Edit: I forgot to add that, for each product I only know the total weekly average and not for example the number of sales for the red t-shirt, sales for the white, and sales for the blue t-shirt. Instead: I only have one number, so for each I get e.g. 300 sales.

Comment: Can you rewrite the problem in terms of the actual business problem you are trying to solve. Leave statistician s to tell you how to create right representation.

Comment: Lay out data you have, and data you don't have with real examples.

Comment: It is very unclear for what data you have eg colour and what data you don't. Eg if you don't have sales data by colour, then you cannot use colour to predict sales??? So it would seem like you should be aggregating the data to the level you have information.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using OLS if you plan to do any statistical inference.  OLS assumes independent observations, which you obviously don't have if the same person appears in your dataset twice.  You should look into [random effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_effects_model) or [mixed effects models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model).  Other models might be appropriate too, depending on the distribution of your response variable.

**Update based on comment**

If all you plan to do is make predictions, you could simply fit your model with some randomly selected training data, and then validate your model on a separate validation dataset. The model that has the smallest [mean squared predicted error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_prediction_error) (or whatever error criteria you want to use) should be used.  I don't think you'd need to concern yourself with weighting -- at least not to arrive at proper variance estimates/standard errors (that's not to say modifying weights may help you obtain better predictions).

Comment: I plan to make predictions, so I guess I should be using for example `lmer` from the `lme4` pakcage in R?

Comment: @Amonet, I updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: @Amonet Statsstudent's edit is right.  Prediction won't care about correlated errors, but inference does.

Comment: Let's say I use `lm(x4 ~  x2 + x3, data = data)`, for now without training or test set. Then my predictions would be valid, despite that observations are in multiple times in the dataset? As you're speaking about weights, won't my model give more weight to observation 1 (line 1 and 2), because it's in twice? Whereas all other observations in this example are in just once?

Comment: I suppose this depends on what you mean by "valid."  Yes, point estimates will be accurate.  Variance estimates will be not.  Each of the two observations will be given equal weight.

Comment: I am purely interested in the point estimates, as my desire is to have an indication of the future sales of the new products. Given the new information (about the time series aspect), does your answer still hold? I'd gladly accept it if I know you still think it's correct :)

Comment: @Amonet, I will have to update my answer later today as my revised answer based on the additional information you provided in your update, will take some time to explain.  Stay tuned. In the meantime, you might want to explore coinjoint analysis:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjoint_analysis

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at that and I'm looking forward for your revised answer.

Comment: I would suggest glmnet package rather than lmer, given you are interested in prediction rather than statistical inference